# Coherence : weblogic.application.ModuleException: No storage-enabled nodes exist for service DistributedSessions

Tags: weblogic, oracle-coherence

I am trying to use Coherence server (separate from my client to store session data) for my weblogic server (client).  I'm getting the error like

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: No storage-enabled nodes exist for service DistributedSessions:com.tangosol.net.RequestPolicyException:No storage-enabled nodes exist for service DistributedSessions
```

Similar question was asked in past in the forum and i have verified all the threads and not able to find the right solution.

Can someone please help?

1) Config on Coherence Server: `Keep tangosol-coherence-override on the Coherence server class path.`

2) Sample of xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE coherence SYSTEM "coherence.dtd">
<coherence>
    <cluster-config>
        <member-identity>
            <cluster-name>ClusterName</cluster-name>
        </member-identity>
        <unicast-listener>
            <address system-property='tangosol.coherence.localhost' />
            <port system-property='tangosol.coherence.localport'>18088</port>
            <well-known-addresses>
                <socket-address id='1'>
                    <address>830.8.119.55</address>
                    <port>18088</port>
                </socket-address>               
            </well-known-addresses>
        </unicast-listener>
        <shutdown-listener>
            <enabled system-property='tangosol.coherence.shutdownhook'>none</enabled>
        </shutdown-listener>
        <logging-config>
            <destination system-property='tangosol.coherence.log'>log4j</destination>
        </logging-config>
    </cluster-config>
</coherence>
```

3) Start the coherence Server with command
`java -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp ${COHERENCE_HOME}/../lib/coherence.jar:${COHERENCE_HOME}/../lib/coherence-web.jar:${COHERENCE_HOME}/../config/ -Dtangosol.coherence.session.localstorage=true com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer  1> ${COHERENCE_HOME}/../logs/stdlog.log 2>&1 &`

4) Output on coherence server startup

```
2017-10-09 10:20:00.561/1.034 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <Info> **(thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded cache configuration from "jar:file:/home/xy6122/coherence/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/coherence-cache-config.xml"**
2017-10-09 10:20:01.041/1.514 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D4> (thread=main, member=n/a): TCMP bound to /830.8.119.55:18088 using SystemSocketProvider
2017-10-09 10:20:04.363/4.836 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <Info> (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): **Created a new cluster "<<ClusterName>>"** with Member(**Id=1, Timestamp=2017-10-09 10:20:01.093, Address=830.8.119.55:18088,** MachineId=65067, Location=site:,machine:zldv6413,process:23334, Role=CoherenceServer, Edition=Grid Edition, Mode=Development, CpuCount=12, SocketCount=6) UID=0x820877370000015F0181BEC5FE2B46A8
2017-10-09 10:20:04.370/4.843 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Started cluster Name=<<ClusterName>>



MasterMemberSet(
  ThisMember=Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2017-10-09 10:20:01.093, Address=830.8.119.55:18088, MachineId=65067, Location=site:,machine:abcdv6413,process:23334, Role=CoherenceServer)
  OldestMember=Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2017-10-09 10:20:01.093, Address=130.8.119.55:18088, MachineId=65067, Location=site:,machine:zldv6413,process:23334, Role=CoherenceServer)
  ActualMemberSet=MemberSet(Size=1
    Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2017-10-09 10:20:01.093, Address=130.8.119.55:18088, MachineId=65067, Location=site:,machine:zldv6413,process:23334, Role=CoherenceServer)
    )
  MemberId|ServiceVersion|ServiceJoined|MemberState
    **1|3.7.1|2017-10-09 10:20:04.363|JOINED**
  RecycleMillis=1200000
  RecycleSet=MemberSet(Size=0
    )
  )

TcpRing{Connections=[]}
IpMonitor{Addresses=0, Timeout=15s}

2017-10-09 10:20:04.412/4.885 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D5> (thread=Invocation:Management, member=1): Service Management joined the cluster with senior service member 1
2017-10-09 10:20:04.681/5.154 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D5> (thread=DistributedCache, member=1): Service DistributedCache joined the cluster with senior service member 1
2017-10-09 10:20:04.780/5.253 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D5> (thread=ReplicatedCache, member=1): Service ReplicatedCache joined the cluster with senior service member 1
2017-10-09 10:20:04.795/5.268 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D5> (thread=OptimisticCache, member=1): Service OptimisticCache joined the cluster with senior service member 1
2017-10-09 10:20:04.803/5.276 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D5> (thread=Invocation:InvocationService, member=1): Service InvocationService joined the cluster with senior service member 1
2017-10-09 10:20:04.806/5.280 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <Info> (thread=main, member=1): 
Services
  (
  ClusterService{Name=Cluster, State=(SERVICE_STARTED, STATE_JOINED), Id=0, Version=3.7.1, OldestMemberId=1}
  InvocationService{Name=Management, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), Id=1, Version=3.1, OldestMemberId=1}
  PartitionedCache{Name=DistributedCache, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), LocalStorage=enabled, PartitionCount=257, BackupCount=1, AssignedPartitions=257, BackupPartitions=0}
  ReplicatedCache{Name=ReplicatedCache, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), Id=3, Version=3.0, OldestMemberId=1}
  Optimistic{Name=OptimisticCache, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), Id=4, Version=3.0, OldestMemberId=1}
  InvocationService{Name=InvocationService, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), Id=5, Version=3.1, OldestMemberId=1}
  )

**Started DefaultCacheServer...**
```

5) Starting the Weblogic server
along with other command line argument provide following
`-Dtangosol.coherence.session.localstorage=false`
so weblogic will store the session data on coherence server and not the local weblogic heap.

6) Kept the same tangosol-coherence-override.xml file on weblogic class path

7) Able to start the weblogic server

8) When deploying the webapplication I can see weblogic client has joined the cluster but deployment fails
`2017-10-09 10:30:48.321/648.794 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member(Id=2, Timestamp=2017-10-09 10:30:48.149, Address=830.8.119.55:18090, MachineId=65067, Location=site:,machine:abcdv6413,process:28222, Role=WeblogicServer) joined Cluster with senior member 1
2017-10-09 10:30:48.655/649.128 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member 2 joined Service Management with senior member 1
2017-10-09 10:30:49.077/649.550 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.16 <D5> (thread=Cluster, member=1): Member 2 joined Service DistributedSessions with senior member 2`

But deployment fails with

`weblogic.application.ModuleException: No storage-enabled nodes exist for service DistributedSessions:com.tangosol.net.RequestPolicyException:No storage-enabled nodes exist for service DistributedSessions`

On weblogic server i have installed coherence-web-spi.war as library and also specificy lib-ref in weblogic.xml

I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file you have to insert all address of your architecture: weblogic server (datastorage=false) and the coherence server:

```
<well-known-addresses>
    <socket-address id='1'>
        <address>830.8.119.55</address>
        <port>18088</port>
    </socket-address>   
    <socket-address id='2'>
        <address>x.x.x.x</address>
        <port>yyy</port>
    </socket-address>              
</well-known-addresses>
```